# Dynamic chaining of Stream

Tags: java

I need to figure out way to dynamically create constructor for Filtered Streams
I have a class:

```
public class Chain1 extends myFilterInputStream


//constructor 1
public Chain1 (InputStream is, RepeatableData data) {
    super(is,data.getData(),data.getKey());
}
//constructor 2
public Chain1 (InputStream in, RepeatableData[] data) {
//return new Chain1 (new Chain1 (is, data[1].getData(),data[1].getKey()), data[2].getData(), data[2].getKey());

  for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
     //create the line above dynamically
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically create constructor"?

Comment: So that constructor2 can take array of objects and chain filters in such a way as yo can do manually. For instance I can do this. new Chain1 (new Chain1 (is, data[1].getData(),data[1].getKey()), data[2].getData(), data[2].getKey()); but I want to do this based on the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to replace your second constructor by something like a factory method, because you need to build the chain before passing it to the super-constructor.

```
public static Chain1 createChain1(InputStream in, RepeatableData[] data){
    if(data == null || data.length == 0){
        // handle invalid params
    }
    InputStream nextStream = in;       
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        nextStream  = new Chain1(nextStream, data[i]);           
    }
    return (Chain1)nextStream;
}
```

Comment: could I create something like this?   `code`     Class<Chain1> _tempClass = (Class<Chain1>) Class.forName("Chain1");
      Constructor<Chain1> ctor = _tempClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
           Chain1 ad = ctor.newInstance(in,data[i]);  //not sure about the rest `code` sorry keep trying to format the code and its not working.

Comment: @P.U What do you mean? Someone who wants to create a chained `Chain1` will have to call this factory method. The factory method uses constructor 1 to create the `Chain1` objects.

Comment: YES!! that worked.  I thought I could just create multiple instance of that class in its constructor and somehow chain those.